# How can I narrow down my SharePoint 2007 View's filter results based on the Group By property?

Tags: sharepoint, listview, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-list

I have a list within SharePoint 2007 and I've created a View that filters based on time ([Today]-30). I also have the View set to Group By a People or Group column. The end result is a View that displays all entries in the past 30 days grouped by individual.

So, what I'd like to do is only include those individuals that have 2 or more entries to display within the view. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0):

Views built through the UI are based on CAML queries, which only allow filters to be applied to items. As you can see from the schema,  filters cannot be applied to group bys.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms415157.aspx

Your options are:

1. Filter it with some combination of sharepoint designer and jquery. This filtering would be done after the results are retrieved from the database, so it wont be ideal.
2. Write a custom web part.

Comment: djeeg -- Thanks for your comment. I kind of figured that it couldn't be done straight within the list view. Do you know more specifically how to do it within SharePoint Designer? I'm up for ideas of how I can get this done. --Brian

Comment: this link explains how to group by more than 2 columns http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2008/11/sharepoint-group-by-on-more-than-2.html, not what you want, but it shows you how to modify the xsl that generates the list, you just need an xsl to show 2+ item groups